# Perl remove text within () characters

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable which may or may not contain text within brackets, e.g.

```
blah blah (soups up)
```

I want to remove anything within and including the brackets, so for this example I'd be left with:

```
blah blah
```

I tried the following substitution but it didn't work as expected:

```
$desc =~ s/(.*?)//gs;
print "fixed desc: $desc\n";
```

prints:

```
fixed desc:
```

As per the discussion, anything, including sub brackets within brackets should be blitz'd

e.g.

```
blah blah (soups up (tomato!) )
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the text is `blah blah (soups (up))`?  Doing this correctly involves counting open and close parentheses, which is hard (if not impossible) to do with regular expressions.

Comment: @JimGarrison good point, anything including sub brackets within the brackets should go

Comment: I haven't kept up with the very latest bells & whistles in Perl regex, so there might be some recent feature for this. However, recursively nested parentheses do not define a "regular language" that is parseable using regex.

Comment: Also, what happens if there is an unmatched parenthesis, or one contained in quotes (are quotes special too)? I.e. the string `Bracket chars are "(" and ")"`.  I suspect you _don't_ want to end up with `Bracket chars are ""`.  In other words, this is a grammar/parsing problem and is much more complex than simple replacement.

Comment: @JimGarrison Perl has supported [recursive regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f_PARNO_%29-%28%3f-_PARNO_%29-%28%3f%2b_PARNO_%29-%28%3fR%29-%28%3f0%29) since 5.10.0.

Comment: Does it also support correctly parsing quoted strings, embedded escaped quotes, etc. etc.  Assuming the OP confirms no need to parse quotes or escapes then I agree a recursive regex is appropriate.  I'm trying to point out that the OP hasn't considered even a small fraction of the possibilities and beyond a certain level of complexity regex is the wrong tool.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche To get an answer you are going to have to better specify the grammar of the strings you want to process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching balanced text is a classic hard regex problem.  For example, how do you deal with `keep (remove) keep (remove)`?  Fortunately it's gotten much easier.  [perlfaq4 covers it](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-find-matching%2fnesting-anything%3f).  You have two choices.

First is to use recursive regexes introduced in 5.10.  `(?R)` says to recurse the whole pattern.

```
m{
    \(                        # Open paren
       (?>
           [^()]   |          # No nested parens OR
           (?R)               # Recurse to check for balanced parens
       )*
    \)                        # Close paren
 }x;
```

However, this doesn't deal with escapes like `(this is \) all in parens)`.

Rather than go into the regex contortions necessary to handle escapes, use a module to build that regex for you.  [Regexp::Common::balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::balanced) and [Regexp::Common::delimited](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::delimited) can do that, and a lot of other hard regex problems, and it will handle escapes.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Common;

my $re = $RE{balanced}{-parens=>"()"};

my $s = "blah blah (soups up (tomato!\) )";

$s =~ s{$re}{};

say $s;    # "blah blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing to note in the most simple case, if you aren't yet worried about some of the edge cases mentioned above, is that the bracket characters are also used for grouping and backreferences in regexes. So you'll need to escape them in your match statement like so:

> $desc =~ s/\(.*\)//gs;

Here's some more info on the topic:
http://perlmeme.org/faqs/regexp/metachar_regexp.html

Second question: What are you intending to do with the question mark in the match? The '*' will match from 0-n occurrences of the previous character, so I'm not sure the '?' is going to do much here.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I thought the question mark was matching anything within the range, e.g. between the brackets.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Brackets in a regex don't match literal brackets in the string. `/^(foo)/` does not match the text `(foo)`, while it does match the text `foo` (and additionally stores `foo` in `$1`).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot running the above code in a test suite seems to be working so far for removing brackets and anything in between.

Comment: This does not handle nested parens.  `"blah blah (soups up (tomato!) )"` becomes `blah blah  )`.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche You haven't shown the code for your test suite, so I can't tell you why you're seeing that. I can tell you that unescaped brackets in a regex do not match literal brackets in the search string: `perl -E'say "match" if "(foo)" =~ /^(foo)/'`. Also see [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html): "...not all characters can be used 'as is' in a match. Some characters, called metacharacters, are reserved for use in regexp notation. The metacharacters are ``{}[]()^$.|*+?\`` ...a metacharacter can be matched by putting a backslash before it..."

Comment: @Schwern - I edited the question mark out of my response to deal with nested parens. The question mark would make the match non-greedy, but it sounds like in this case we want to match up to and including the last paren.

Comment: More info on greedy and non-greedy matches here: http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/non-greedy-perl-regex.html

Comment: @heyhey2k That kinda makes it worse. It's going to capture everything between the first `(` and the last `)`. For example, `out1 (in1) out2 (in2)` will return just `out1 ` when it should return `out1  out2 `. The regex needs to take balancing into account.

Comment: @Schwern - Point taken, but it wasn't clear from the question that these cases needed to be taken into account.